# Directly send signals to USB using Python

Tags: python, c++, c, usb, hardware

How can I set HIGH or LOW to a usb port  connections using Python.

This could be used in come custom usb device.

For Example,

Consider I have a LED connected to the usb port(DATA Line) .

Now through the code I want to blink it or control it.

Now this can be easily achieved by using any micro controller, Arduino, Raspberry Pi

But I want to achieve this with with a normal computer and python.

## [EDIT]

Can I achieve this by making a **C** or **C++** API and make a wrapper to use it in **Python**. Is yes then what will be the best way to achieve it?

### NOTE :

My main objective isn't just blinking some LED. I just gave it as an example.

I want to be able to directly control the USB ports.

Quoting : [https://www.cmd-ltd.com/advice-centre/usb-chargers-and-power-modules/usb-and-power-module-product-help/usb-data-transfer-guide/#:~:text=How%20is%20data%20sent%20across,amounts%20known%20as%20'packets'](https://www.cmd-ltd.com/advice-centre/usb-chargers-and-power-modules/usb-and-power-module-product-help/usb-data-transfer-guide/#:%7E:text=How%20is%20data%20sent%20across,amounts%20known%20as%20%27packets%27).

> Within the standard USB 2.0 connector you can see four metal strips. The outer two strips are the positive and ground of the power supply. The two central strips are dedicated to carrying data.

> With the newer USB 3.0 connector, the data transfer speed is increased by the addition of extra data-carrying strips; four extra signalling wires help USB 3.0 achieve its super speed.

I want to set the values of the Data pins.

By my saying HIGH LOW please don't misunderstand that I want to set the value to +5V and GND. But I mean to control its value directly via my code without any external driver present in the computer.

I mentioned **HIGH** **LOW** to just make the language simple and so that it is easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controlling components like LEDs from devices like Arduino and Raspberry Pi are done using GPIO pins. In contrast, USB is designed for data transfer and not for maintaining more constant high or low signals like GPIO. It also consumes different voltage and current levels than GPIO pins and could potentially damage components meant for GPIO.

However, you can get USB to GPIO adapters for this purpose (see [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/61290/usb-to-gpio-module) for an example discussion on these options).

In terms of Python, you can use packages such as [PyUSB](https://pyusb.github.io/pyusb/) or the [libusb](https://pypi.org/project/libusb/) Python wrapper to control/transfer data/communicate with USB devices (such as the USB to GPIO adapters). The companies providing the adapters might also have designed their own easy-to-use Python package to wrap around a lower-level driver (probably written in C). See this [USB controlled LED device](https://www.blinkstick.com/) as an example with its own Python driver. The drivers are just software programs that take in relatively simple commands from the user for what they want a device to do. They then encapsulate the lower-level complexities required for following a protocol to communicate the user's intention to the USB device and controlling the USB port at the lowest possible software level.

Comment: Blinking LED is not my priority I just gave it as a simple example. I want to be able to directly control the USB ports. And the libraries you mentioned (PyUSB) is for control of standard USB  based devices not for directly controlling the ports.

Comment: It would seem that serial communication ports like USB are much more complex than you are alluding to. You cannot directly control the signals on the USB pins through software. The pins are first controlled by analog circuitry, then digital hardware, which then eventually takes instructions from a low-level software driver. You will never have direct control over the exact signals on the pins because the hardware controllers ensure that the signals are limited to high-frequency waveforms that abide by the USB communication protocol for serially sending packets of data between devices.

Comment: here direct control will then mean as far as we can go by software

Comment: What type of device exactly are you wanting to connect to the pins? The only meaningful connection you can form with it is by connecting it to another device that has its own USB port as well to reinterpret the signal being sent, unless you want to do things like view the signal waveforms on an oscilloscope. The furthest you can go with controlling it from software roughly speaking is whatever is available from a C code USB driver. You could write a custom C driver but you probably wouldn't get any further than if using the existing ones.

Comment: I am not exactly planning to connect something specific but my only intention is to study how can control this. And i think the C driver would be quite close to what i want

Comment: And if i am able to write such a driver i will surely post it here

Comment: Yeah, if your goal is to learn more, then writing your own driver could be a steep learning curve but can be a great way to learn more about how a computer works at a lower level, and how an operating system communicates with the many hardware modules (such as USB ports) in a computer. If you want to write a driver for Linux then I'd recommend looking at a textbook called *Linux Device Drivers*.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve that for several reasons:

- The USB port has its own protocol of connection. Data is transmitted in packets with starting and ending bits. The negotiation and handshake process is done in the hardware layer between microchips. This process also selects the communication speed in the bidirectional data line. You have to direct access to the pin (like GPIO) to turn LEDs ON and Off or create your own connection protocol. This cannot be done in USB.
- There are also voltage and current limitations. The data line is not +5 and GND. The data line is 2.8v for D+ and 0.3v for D- and both with respect to the GND. The data is transmitted and received differentially (D+ with respect to D-) and they are not compared with the GND for 1s and 0s.

The button line is you have no direct control over USB.

Comment: I did make some changes in the question to clarify it. Blinking an LED is not my priority and neither is Setting it to +5 or GND but to directly control the usb port using its protocol itself via my code.