# How to send serial signal with Python?

Tags: python, serial-port, usb

I am trying to create a USB device that vibrates whenever a key is pressed on the computer it is connected to. I have a working Python script that detects key presses, but I need it to send a signal to a USB device (which hasn’t been made yet). How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

This may help a little bit: [Directly send signals to USB using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66815102/directly-send-signals-to-usb-using-python)

To minimize what might be helfup:

> Controlling components like LEDs from devices like Arduino and Raspberry Pi are done using GPIO pins. In contrast, USB is designed for data transfer and not for maintaining more constant high or low signals like GPIO. It also consumes different voltage and current levels than GPIO pins and could potentially damage components meant for GPIO.

> However, you can get USB to GPIO adapters for this purpose (see here for an example discussion on these options).

> **In terms of Python, you can use packages such as [PyUSB](https://pyusb.github.io/pyusb/) or the [libusb](https://pypi.org/project/libusb/) Python wrapper to control/transfer data/communicate with USB devices (such as the USB to GPIO adapters). The companies providing the adapters might also have designed their own easy-to-use Python package to wrap around a lower-level driver (probably written in C). See this USB controlled LED device as an example with its own Python driver. The drivers are just software programs that take in relatively simple commands from the user for what they want a device to do. They then encapsulate the lower-level complexities required for following a protocol to communicate the user's intention to the USB device and controlling the USB port at the lowest possible software level.**

Answer (score 0):

Using [pyserial](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial.html) you can read from a serial device and also write to it.

```py
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')  # open serial port
ser.write(b'hello')     # this would depend on the protocol for the USB device
ser.close()             # close port
```